# disable swipe in ionic slidebox

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In ionic we have slideBox.I want to disable swipe .I want it to slide on button click.How can i do it?

I have tried `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(false)` in my controller  but it is not working.

According to this link http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionicslideboxdelegate-disable-all-swiping/6391 i have to disable in the scope of the slidebox but how to access the scope of the element and apply it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The proper place to do it is in `ng-init`

```
<ion-slide-box ng-init="lockSlide()">
```

and have the respective function in your controller

```
.controller('sliders', function($scope, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
    $scope.lockSlide = function () {
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide( false );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your html file put active-slide="slidestop($index)"

```
<ion-slide-box active-slide="slidestop($index)">
</ion-slide-box>
```

And in Controller class that function "slidestop"

```
$scope.slidestop = function(index) {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(false);
}
```

Comment: I am currently working with ionic framework. I also faced the same problem with the slidebox, this idea really works for my app, @kash thanks for sharing.....

Comment: but it showing an error as well  Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'slidestop($index)' used with directive 'ionSlideBox' is non-assignable!

Comment: It actually works @MohammadFaizanKhan but the error persists. Did you manage to fix the error?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is probably that the slidebox needs to be rendered before you can disable sliding. So in your controller, use a timeout:

```
$timeout(function(){
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(0);
},0);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your html add

```
<ion-slide-box active-slide="slidestop" does-continue="false">
```

And in your controller add

```
$timeout(function(){
$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(false);
},0);
```

Comment: This `$timeout` did the job. Thank you! :-)